# SQL Server: Computed Expression error

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, calculated-columns

Here's a table with a computed column in SQL Server 2005:

```
CREATE TABLE footable AS
  [identifier] nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
  [result]     AS CASE 
    WHEN [identifier] like '%\[%]' escape '\'
    THEN LEFT( [identifier], CHARINDEX('[',[identifier]) - 1 )
    END
```

Here's what I'm expecting:

```
identifier      result
======================
foo[bar]        foo
foo             NULL
```

This worked a few days ago, and has been working for over a year.

Then yesterday, I started getting this error when inserting or updating with `identifier` values that had no `[`, when a NULL would be the expected result:

```
Invalid length parameter passed to the left function.
```

Now, today, it's working again.

Why would SQL Server be attempting to solve the `LEFT()` function when the `CASE` is not true?

More importantly, why is it working one day and not the next?

I was also creating some indexed views yesterday, though not covering either of these columns. Could one of the SET options required for indexing a view cause the database to start throwing errors for an expression like this?

Comment: If you get the areas when inserting or updating as opposed to when selecting I suspect they must be coming from somewhere else (e.g. triggers).

Comment: What if the first character was a '[' for an identifier yesterday?  Then you'd be asking for the left 0 characters.  Maybe the pattern needs to be '_%\[%]' escape '\'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use

```
N'[^[]%\[%]' escape N'\'
```

That should handle the possibility that the first character is a [.

Or, if you want to return a non-null (empty string?) in that case, use a nested CASE to handle the condition of CHARINDEX returning 1.

By the way, you don't really need that escape character or escape clause.  You can use [[] to match the [ character:

```
N'[^[]%[[]%]'
```

But, that's a matter of personal taste.  I can see how the escaped version is a little clearer